# how to know when all promises are resolved while using multiple promises

Tags: angular

I'm making an angular app with node.js. I want to wait for all the promises to resolve, then do some working. My code looks like:

**myComponent.ts**

```
this.myService.loadData(param).then((response) => {
  console.log("loaded");
  // raise a flag here. all promises are resolved.
});
```

**myService.ts**

```
public loadData(param): Promise <any>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.loadMoreData(param).then((data) => {
    resolve("data loaded");
  });
});
}

public loadMoreData(param): Promise <any>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.loadSomeMoreData(param).then(() => {
    resolve("more data loaded");
  });
});
}

public loadSomeMoreData(param): Promise <any>{
  this.loadSomeMoreData(param).then(() => {
    this.loadSomeMoreMoreData(param).then(() => {
    resolve("more data loaded");
 });
});
}

...
And So on like this.
```

My code looks like above chaining. Actually, I have separated each task in the separate function and I have to know when each task is completed. And overall it should tell me in `myComponent.ts` that all promises are resolved.
I have also tried

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
 console.log(values);
});
```

But as you can see all my promises are in separate service and being called upon the output returned by previous promise. so I can't get all of them resolved in `myComponent.ts`.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Something like this may work: Add a return in all your promises, this way you will not break the chain and then finally listen to the topmost promise

Comment: `return` after `resolve` or before?

Comment: CommercialSuicide has alread answered... although I made this example.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-43dk7i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Why do you wrap you already existing Promise into a `new Promise`? You could just return the Promise chain from the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can return promises from your services like

```
public loadData(param): Promise <any> {
   return this.loadMoreData(param);
}

public loadMoreData(param): Promise <any>{
   return this.loadSomeMoreData(param);
}

public loadSomeMoreData(param): Promise <any>{
   return this.loadSomeMoreData(param);
}
```

and in this call you can just add `catch` or `reject` block

```
this.myService.loadData(param).then((response) => {
  console.log("loaded");
  // raise a flag here. all promises are resolved.
}).catch(...);
```

If the flow is not go into the `catch` means that your promises were resolved and everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You already wrapped every next async call into `new Promise` and `resolve` it after inner request ends up, so your promise chain is actually ready, all you need is just to call `loadData` method, and `then` block inside this method fill be fired only after `loadSomeMoreMoreData` response is got, so looks like this behavior is what you're looking for.

PS: You also forgot to return a `Promise` in `loadSomeMoreData` method.

Comment: Wrapping an already existing Promise into a `new Promise` is an anti pattern. There is absolutely no need to do that. With that approach you actually break the chain, instead of creating one.

Comment: @t.niese, thanks for the correction, i've made a mistake, already corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution that seems to match more your expectation is the following:

```
//this is in a Service1
public loadData1(param): Promise <any>{
    return asyncMethod1(param); //this return a promise
}

//this is in a Service2
public loadData2(data1): Promise <any>{
    return asyncMethod2(data1); //this return a promise
}

//this is in a Service3
public loadData3(data2): Promise <any>{
    return asyncMethod3(data2); //this return a promise
}

etc...
```

in your component:

```
let data1$=Observable.fromPromise(Service1.loadData1(xxx));
let data2$=data1$.flatMap(Service2.loadData2),
let data3$=data2$.flatMap(Service3.loadData3),
data3$.subscribe(result=>/*use the final result*/);
```